# UC3843 Clamping Error Amplifier Voltage

Tags: operational-amplifier, pwm, error-amplifier

I'm trying to design a constant current solenoid driver using UC3843 PWM IC.
The datasheet is available at https://www.ti.com/product/UC3843

Since I'm only utilizing constant current function using current sensing, I don't
need voltage feedback compensation using error amplifier. Hence I'm simply clamping
COMP pin to required voltage using external voltage divider (max voltage = 5V).
The VFB pin is simply grounded using a 1K resistor. The circuit works and operates as a constant
current driver very well, but I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing things.
Should I just clamp COMP voltage or should I configure error amplifier as an unity gain amplifier and
provide target voltage to the input pin?

Here is the block diagram of UC3843

[image: UC3843 Block Diagram]

This is my configuration for VFB and COMP

[image: VFB,COMP]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current sensing is used to limit the output current to the voltage imposed by the error amplifier. If you force this to some predefined value you will still have output current given by the output voltage. It doesn't work as a current generator because if you'll change the load you'll get a different current, set by the voltage at the `COMP` pin. Therefore you will have a *voltage* generator, with a current-mode control, but without voltage conrtol (not taken into account in the feedback loop).

If you want a current generator, then you'll need a second current sensor (resistor, what have you) on the *load* side, where the DC current is, and which will give you the voltage to feed to the IC as the current to regulate. This will require an external amplifier since the reference voltage for the internal error amplifier is a fixed `2.5` V. So you'll need to amplify the sensed current to this value. This means that your loop will have to account for this amplification factor, which may be in the order of tens (e.g. a `0.25` Ω resistor for a `0.5` A will mean a `0.125` V, which will need 20x amplification). So, unless you're making this a high-current generator, it might not be a good choice. There are constant *output* current controllers. The fact that this is a current-mode controller, it doesn't mean that it refers to the output *DC* current, rather to its controlling of the pulsed current, to serve the output voltage.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!