# UC3843 doesn't work as expected

Tags: buck, constant-current

I tried to implement a constant current driver "May be constant power driver" using a [UC3843](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/uc3843), simply by disabling the EA by pulling it down to GND and clamping the COMP voltage between 1.4V ~ 4.4 V to realize the peak current limit that is stated in the documentation:

$$I_{pk} = \frac{V_{comp} - 1.4}{3 \cdot R_s}$$

I set the COMP voltage through a voltage divider (R3, R4).
I pull down the COMP voltage for shutdown when required.
The circuit is expected to work as a current-limited float buck converter.

However, the output current is not constant - it changes when the load changes. Also, when I measure the COMP voltage, it reads 6 V, while it should be around 1.8 V.

Typical test values:
VD = 12 V
R3 = 10 kΩ
R4 = 5.6 kΩ
R8 (R<sub>s</sub>) = 0.1 Ω
Frequency: 245 kHz
L1 = 100 μH
U1: UC3843 from ST
All resistors are 1%

These R3, R4 values should produce 1.8 V from a 5 V V<sub>ref</sub>, but this is not the case, it's 6 V.
With V<sub>comp</sub> = 1.8 V the peak current should be around 1.3 A (but it changes with the load).

This is a typical schematic:

[image]

Comment: Pulling FB to ground does not "disable" the EA, it forces its output to the positive rail, since FB is the inverting input and there's a fixed 2.5V reference on the non-inverting input. Refer to the part datasheet.

Comment: @AdamLawrence Regardless the term I used, in the documentation (TI, ON datasheets) they state that EA FB input could be held to GND, then the COMP voltage to be clamped to define the peak current limit according to the mentioned equation ..

Do I miss something ?

Comment: XY problem. You have a requirement that you don't adequately state and, you have a circuit implementation that does not do what you want. Who can say what you want. You need to be explicit and say what you are trying to achieve. Nobody can help you without that info.

Comment: @Andyaka:
I thought I stated that "However, the output current is not constant, it changes with the load changes ! Also when I measure the COMP voltage it reads 6V while it should be around 1.8V!" & id doesn't comply with the documentation say ..
Then I detailed the circuit with the expected & the real output !!!
Before I ask I checked all UC3843 posted questions, mostly all follow the same paradigm !
What else is missing ?!

Comment: You said this is what you are trying to achieve: *I tried to implement a constant current driver "May be constant power driver"* <-- ambiguity

Comment: @Andyaka:
I didn't find any ambiguity, Please check just alike previews questions:

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/603602/uc3843-pwm-duty-cycle-variation-with-temperature

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/559984/uc3843-clamping-error-amplifier-voltage

Comment: I think, the inductance of L1 is far too big for 245 kHz. The current limit is not reached with your test load, try 22 uH.

Comment: What is the desired range of Vin, Vout, and Iout?

Comment: Note that ST's error amp is more powerful: https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/uc2842b.pdf and neither datasheet specifies maximum sink/source COMP current.

Comment: @TimWilliams The common buck formulas gives 69uH for L1, so I choose 100uH, Vin is regulated 12V from 10A SMPS, Vout is float as the constant current is only the concern, Iout should be around 1.4A, What happen is it changes with the load (1.3 with 8Ohms, 2.4 with 4Ohms), Some other guy says that as the schematic is, if VComp = 6V then the IC may be damaged or a fake clone !

Comment: 1.3A and 2.4A are "around" 1.4A, for some values of "around". Can you specify a range of voltages and currents you want to meet? No current source is perfect, there is always some variation; asking for a perfect one is meaningless. The question is then: how much, over what range?

Comment: @TimWilliams .. May be my English is not clear enough .. 1.4A is the target current, so 1.3 to 1.5 is "around 1.4" .. But 2.4A is so far that there is no current limiting !!, 
The circuit should limit the current within the components tolerance "5% max" but not 200% !!!

Comment: Language, perhaps, but not your English -- which is good by the way :) -- the language of engineering. Consider if V(J2) = GND, what could current be? Well, hopefully not much, it would be unreasonable to expect it to regulate there. At what voltage should it start, then? Likewise, if V(J2) = VDD, we might still expect it to be able to regulate (it won't, but a suitable controller could), but we might also not care because a short-circuit load isn't a useful condition. So you wish the current to be within +/-5 or 10% over most of the voltage range?